# payload in messaging.onMessage().then(function(payload) is undefind from fcm angularjs(1.6)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, firebase-cloud-messaging

i use fcm in angularjs app
i can connect to firebase and get token an i can able to get messagin in console

```
>>firebaseDependencies: Object { app: {…}, appConfig: {…}, installations: {…}, … }
​
onMessageCallback: null
​
swRegistration: ServiceWorkerRegistration { installing: null, scope: "http://localhost:8080/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope", updateViaCache: "imports", … }
​
vapidKey: "BHlbwdTi9t_8-FMCh2X991P_KEuIsWMoKJSWYqk44B8AtWRhoehYpZ-GkHqnSfya9ANiTMLTUZxbpK1ASIgmLBc"
​
<prototype>: {…}
​​
app: 
​​
constructor: function rt(e)​​
deleteToken: function deleteToken()​​
getServiceWorkerRegistration: function getServiceWorkerRegistration()​​
getToken: function getToken()​​
logEvent: function logEvent(n, r)​​
messageEventListener: function messageEventListener(o)​​
onMessage: function onMessage(e)​​
onTokenRefresh: function onTokenRefresh()​​
requestPermission: function requestPermission()​​
setBackgroundMessageHandler: function setBackgroundMessageHandler()​​
usePublicVapidKey: function usePublicVapidKey(e)​​
useServiceWorker: function useServiceWorker(e)
```

i use

```
>>https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
data
{
 "to" : "dXECW-D1bx0GuaF6f-s0Ms:APA91bFjAL7-0WuqYuscLCRZJ0ojJqk1Qm8NLu21yNo8elXZy1VPzy5OGZhzRVkLTo7SSZgP9cjdx-Xq_c2jqgs2O73tYEUmfGuhflNbcq-aEVoTX4JslM1slgdQJSLvf9Kgh3X3rJQD",

>>"notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    }
}
```

for get notification but

```
 >> messaging.onMessage().then((payload) => {

    console.log('Message received. ', payload);
    alert("message",payload)
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    // Update the UI to include the received message.
    // appendMessage(payload);
    // [END_EXCLUDE]});
```

dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use old version FCM JS and set it manually because it's not compatible with your angular.